# Exception Handler for normal AND ajax request for logging purpose

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, exception

Can someone give me a working example of an `ExceptionHandler` which extends `ExceptionHandlerWrapper` for both **normal and ajax request**. I don't want to use a filter. I want all my exception handling to be in one entry place for logging purpose.

In Omnifaces we have the `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` but **only** for ajax request. How can I refactor this class in order to take into account both types of request?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Make an attempt and come back here with specific questions. "Write my code for me" is not an acceptable question.

Comment: Sorry Stonz2 but I didn't mean that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to render the error page inside my CustomExceptionHandler, I use inside a utility method such a statement which identify the type of request (normal or ajax)

```
if (context.getPartialViewContext().isAjaxRequest()) {
      ViewHandler viewHandler = context.getApplication().getViewHandler();
      UIViewRoot viewRoot = viewHandler.createView(context, errorPageLocation);
      context.setViewRoot(viewRoot);
      context.getPartialViewContext().setRenderAll(true);
      context.renderResponse();
} else {
      NavigationHandler nav = context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
      nav.handleNavigation(context, null, errorPageLocation);
      context.renderResponse();
}
```

By this way I can handle both request effectively in my CustomExceptionHandler

Answer (score 0):

In the Wrapper you can use, if you want to detect the type of request:

```
context == null || !context.getPartialViewContext().isAjaxRequest()
```

Also recommend you to integrate the WrapperHandler with  [Deltaspike Exception Control](https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/jsf.html#_intergration_with_exception_control_from_deltaspike_0_6)

And finally a common way to redirect (working for both types of requests):

```
public static void redirect(FacesContext fc, String view) {
    ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
    String path = ec.encodeResourceURL(fc.getApplication().getViewHandler().getActionURL(fc, view));
    try {
        ec.redirect(path);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Tvori, Thanks for your comment. Your redirect works only when we have a normal request. On the other hand we need for an ajax request to force JSF to render @All the page. so according to my previous example I can use your 'redirect(FacesContext fc, String view)' in the 'else' part only. Do you agree ?

Comment: The method is working for both types of requests. JSF.redirect(facesContext, "/directory/error.jsf");